# If an after-effect cannot be fulfilled, can the action leading to that after-effect be performed?

Tags: arkham-horror-card-game

In the Carnevale of Horrors expansion, there are locations that contain consequences for leaving the locations, such as

> **Forced** - After you leave Rialto Bridge: Lose 1 action.

or

> **Forced** - After you leave Academia Bridge: Lose 2 resources.

If I do not have the named lost items available, can I still leave the location?  I presumed that if the designers intended for investigators to pay the cost in order to leave, it would be clearly worded as "when leaving" or simply "Spend 2 resources to leave" etc, so have played it accordingly for example using up all but one of my actions before leaving a location that will make me lose an action 'after' leaving.

Comment: I believe that you are correct in your interpretation. Since I can't find anything in the rules to support that, I will leave my answer in this comment.

Comment: I thought there was something in the rules relating to when some effect couldn’t be executed, but I’m not sure now whether I’m misremembering and it was from an Eldritch Horror faq.

Answer (score 1):

You have played it correctly.

Abilities using the **After** keyword initiaite once you have finished resolving the trigger, not before, and when resolving a **Forced** ability, if it cannot change the state of the game, it just does not trigger at all.

From the [rules reference](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/filer_public/c4/b0/c4b0d66c-d79e-411b-bdb5-b5d8c457d4bc/ahc01_rules_reference_web.pdf) (page 2 under **Forced Abilities**):

> - If a forced ability does not have the potential to
>     change the game state, the ability does not initiate.

and on page 3:

> - A forced ability with a timing point beginning with the
>     word “after...” automatically initiates immediately after that
>     timing point’s impact upon the game state has resolved.

This means that as soon as the investigator has finished moving out of the location, they would then lose the listed actions/resources - it is an aftereffect of leaving, not a price you need to pay to leave.